# Alternative for exception.message in Camel

Tags: xml, exception, apache-camel

Currently the following logging is being used :

```
loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Exception in route while processing message ${exception.message}"/>
```

Looking for an alternative for `exception.message` so that I could print the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already try [exception.stacktrace](http://camel.apache.org/simple)? It is available since Camel 2.6.

Documentation says:
`Camel 2.6. Refer to the exception.stracktrace on the exchange. Result is null if no exception set on exchange. Will fallback and grab caught exceptions (Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT) if the Exchange has any.`